# Are "Apk" and "Amp peak-to-peak" the same thing?

Tags: current, current-measurement

Folks,

What is the difference between "Amp pk or Apk" vs "Amp pk-pk (or Amp peak to peak?)"

Are they the same thing?

Comment: Could you post links to where you saw each of these abbreviations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amp pk is the peak value of the current while Amp pk-pk is the peak to peak value of the current.  Thus they are not the same. For example, current in the form of a sine wave that has a peak value of 1 ampere has a peak to peak value of 2 amperes.

Comment: Agreed, but I'm not sure I see many instances where Ap-p would be a useful mesurement. Are there any instances which readily come to your mind where this would be an important figure to know/measure?

Answer (score 0):

Voltage has a "peak to peak" ration, which is usually written as Vp-p. However, unlike voltage, which is actually a measure of *difference* betwee2 potentials (rather than an absolute value), current is usally expressed as an absolute value (in number of columbs passing a given point per second [amps]).

Thus, when measuring current in a fluctuating circuit, I would expect the measurement to be in "Peak Amps," rather than "Peak-to-Peak." Peak amps would give the maximum current through a circuit, while peak-to-peak voltage potential shows the maximum *difference* between voltage potentials in the circuit.